# Variable Undefined in PHP

Tags: php, null, if-statement, isset

I have 5 fields in my DB:

```
test1 = 1, test2 = 1, test3 = NULL, test4 = NULL, test5 = NULL
```

PHP code:

```
if(isset($result['test1'])){$test1= "Test1"; echo $test1};

if(isset($result['test2'])){$test2= "Test2"; echo $test2};

if(isset($result['test3'])){$test3= "Test3"; echo $test3};

if(isset($result['test4'])){$test4= "Test4"; echo $test4};

if(isset($result['test5'])){$test5= "Test5"; echo $test5};

$total = implode(", ", array_filter(array($test1, $test2, $test3, $test4, $test5)));

echo $total;
```

Finaly Output:

`Undefined Variable test3 in Line 7`

`Undefined Variable test4 in Line 7`

`Undefined Variable test5 in Line 7`

Test1, Test2

I came up with 3 possible ways to hopefully run the code with NULL values to see if I will get a blank page with no error, unfortunately, they all gave me "Underfined Variable" error:

1. `if(isset($result['test3'])){$test3= "OK"; echo $test3};`
2. `if(!empty($result['test3'])){$test3= "OK"; echo $test3};`
3. `if($result['test3']=='1'){$test3= "OK"; echo $test3};`

Help? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please slow down and take some time to format the code properly so that people can read it.

Comment: what do you want to see in $total when the field is NULL?

Comment: Is there a reason for `array_filter`?

Comment: so array_filter can filter the variables with NULL values, so it will only implode the variables with values in it

Comment: Those errors are normal. If you don't declare/initialize the variables used in line 7 (assuming this is the line with $total = implode...) PHP will throw the undefined variable message. At present the declarations are limited to the scope of the if statements. Try defining them beforehand ($test1=""...) or adopt yi_H's solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(isset($result['test1'])){$test1= "Test1"; echo $test1} else { $test1="Abrakadabra"; }
```

Comment: i just name it NULL instead of Abrakadabra

Comment: I'm glad this helped but whatever you're doing you probably doing it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it without `array_filter`:

```
 $result = array();

 if(!empty($result['test1'])){$result[] =  "Test1"; echo $test1;}
 ...

 $total = implode(", ", $result);
```

Comment: i will play with this code. I think I like this logic. thanks for the extra help!